# How to show hybris custom extension log in kibana?

Tags: logging, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using Commerce Cloud 1905 on public cloud edition. I would like to know, how can I show, logs from my custom extension in Kibana. What necessary log configuration, I need to add?

In my log4j configuration, I tried to use console appender, but I couldn't see it in Kibana dashboard, after doing necessary filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain the logging configuration, with desired level in manifest.json file.
Redeploy the build.
Changing log level on fly will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure your extension package for logging in properties file ?

ex - log4j.logger.(packagename)=info,debug.

Also, you can refer to below link to fine-tune your kibana logs

https://enable.cx.sap.com/media/Access+and+Utilize+Centralized+Logging+-++SAP+Commerce+Cloud/1_gz5ol0f7

PS: You should have approved partner ID (S User) to access the above video.